# ASN1_INTEGER to ASN1_STRING

Tags: c, openssl, x509

I am using openssl to get data about x509 certificate.
Is there a way to convert ASN1_INTEGER to ASN1_STRING, which can than easily be transformed to char array? Is there a way to convert it to any other human readable format?

EDIT: I'm using openssl compiled for iOS, as I am having the iOS project. Here is the code I am using to extract the serial number from the certificate:

```
ASN1_INTEGER *serial = X509_get_serialNumber(certificateX509);
long value = ASN1_INTEGER_get(serial);
NSLog(@"Serial %ld", value);
```

`certificateX509` is a valid X509 object and I have managed to get some other fields from it (issuer name, expiry date and so on)

EDIT 2:
I finally came to a solution, which may not be the most straightforward one:

```
 ASN1_INTEGER *serial = X509_get_serialNumber(certificateX509);
 BIGNUM *bnser = ASN1_INTEGER_to_BN(serial, NULL);
 int n = BN_num_bytes(bnser);
 unsigned char outbuf[n];
 int bin = BN_bn2bin(bnser, outbuf);
 char *hexbuf = (char*) outbuf;
```

hexBuf then contains characters whose value needs to be read as hex integer in order to retrieve logical values.
I use NSMutableString to create a human readable string:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6x", hexbuf[i]];
    [str appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", temp]];
}
```

If there is a simpler way, I would really like to know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came to a solution, which may not be the most straightforward one:

```
 ASN1_INTEGER *serial = X509_get_serialNumber(certificateX509);
 BIGNUM *bnser = ASN1_INTEGER_to_BN(serial, NULL);
 int n = BN_num_bytes(bnser);
 unsigned char outbuf[n];
 int bin = BN_bn2bin(bnser, outbuf);
 char *hexBuf = (char*) outbuf;
```

hexBuf then contains characters whose value needs to be read as hex integer in order to retrieve logical values.
I use NSMutableString to create a human readable string:

```
 NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6x", hexbuf[i]];
    [str appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", temp]];
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The ascii hex conversion be done more simply using the built in BN_bn2hex(BIGNUM *) function

```
ASN1_INTEGER *serial = X509_get_serialNumber(certificateX509);
BIGNUM *bnser = ASN1_INTEGER_to_BN(serial, NULL);
char *asciiHex = BN_bn2hex(bnser);
```

Comment: The returned char* should be freed after being used.

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is that you can extract the value of the ASN1_INTEGER as a normal C integer:

```
#include <openssl/asn1.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  long value;
  ASN1_INTEGER asn1int = {0};

  ASN1_INTEGER_set(&asn1int, 42);
  value = ASN1_INTEGER_get(&asn1int);
  printf("The value is %ld.\n", value);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled like this:

```
gcc -Wall -o sploots sploots.c -lcrypto
```

this produces the output:

```
The value is 42.
```

To have the value as a string in an array of char, use `snprintf`.

I suspect there are also possibilities for using the BIO printing routines to dump the value to a BIO of some sort (perhaps a memory BIO).  However, this approach seems simpler.

The way I arrived at this answer is that I looked through the OpenSSL headers for ASN1_INTEGER.  After looking around for suitable APIs for a BIO-based solution, I noticed the ASN1_INTEGER_get function.

Looking around in OpenSSL header files is typically the way I learn how to use OpenSSL, since so much of the API is undocumented or incorrectly or incompletely documented.

Comment: Not sure what he's asking about, but for certificate serial numbers it's probably not very useful. For example, I've checked one certificate and the serial number is "‎3c 08 cf ee be 9f eb c4 2b b1 3e e0 3d 62 0b df". It's true that there's no other way but opening the header files and digging out the information, though.

Comment: you are right, that doesn't work for me. I always get -1 as a long value

Comment: It sounds like you're not getting an ASN1_INTEGER out of the certificate.  Perhaps it's a BIGNUM?  Can you add the code you used to extract it from the certificate to the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a readable NSString, `BN_bn2dec` is more consize than `BN_bn2hex` or `BN_bn2bin`.
No need to mess with hex encoding.

Here's my way, in iOS/ObjC, using `pod 'OpenSSL-Universal', '1.0.2.10'` :

```
ASN1_INTEGER *serialAsn1 = X509_get_serialNumber(certX509);
BIGNUM *serialBigNumber = ASN1_INTEGER_to_BN(serialAsn1, NULL);
char *serialChar = BN_bn2dec(serialBigNumber);

NSString *serialString = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char *) serialChar
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me to get the serial number in hex:

```
 ASN1_INTEGER* serial = X509_get_serialNumber(X509_certificate_ptr);
    BIGNUM* bn = ASN1_INTEGER_to_BN(serial, NULL);
    if (!bn) {
        // log here "Unable to convert ASN1INTEGER to BN";
        return "";
    }

    char* hex = BN_bn2hex(bn);
    if (!hex) {
        // Log here "Unable to convert BN to hex string";
        return "";
    }

    cout << hex; // this is your serial number. Can be converted using std::to_string()

    BN_free(bn);
    ASN1_INTEGER_free(serial);
    OPENSSL_free(hex);
    return serial_number;
```

Without error checking and memory management the code is basically:

```
ASN1_INTEGER* serial = X509_get_serialNumber(X509_certificate_ptr);
BIGNUM* bn = ASN1_INTEGER_to_BN(serial, NULL);
char* hex = BN_bn2hex(bn);
```